# Using History.js without "back" function

Tags: javascript, history.js

I'm using History.js and i'm adding states on "next page" clicks.
I need to change url on every page change (next, previous), but when clicked "back" in browser i need to get to the page before started paging.

To be clear:
    I'm in some global page, i want to search something;
    I enter Search results page;
    When i change results page i change url to be more user-friendly;
    When i click "back" in the browser, i want to get to "global page", so like i'm residing in the Search page and the page before is Global page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

For those who meet this situation. You should use replaceState. It will replace url in browser but doesn't add new item in history!